# How to add "Where did you hear about us ?" dropdown in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

I want to add the "How did you hear about us?" drop-down in the order confirmation page for first-time users to my store. And add values like Facebook, from friends etc..

How can I achieve this in Magento 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1 : Create checkout_onepage_success.xml file in**

> app\code[Vendor][Namespace]\view\frontend\layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="custom.order.success"
                template="[Vendor]_[Namespace]::order/success.phtml" after="-">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2 : Create success.phtml in**

> app\code[Vendor][Namespace]\view\frontend\templates\order\

```
<?php
echo "Here Additional Information"; //Bussiness logic
```

You can add the select drop-down input field or HTML and add your logic or Load the order and customer data accordingly to show the dropdown.